# PyInstaller, Windows10: как получить путь к папке appdata/local/temp

Tags: python, pyinstaller

При запуске *exe'шника*, который собран с помощью *pyinstaller*, все внутренности этого *exe'шника* распаковываются в папку `DISK:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI000000` (цифры меняются с кажым запуском).

Однако, после завершения команды (`sys.exit()` / `os.system('exit')` / `os.system('taskkill /IM cmd.exe /F')` ) эти временные папки не удаляются. В результате, если запустить программу раз 100, то создается 100 этих временных папок, которые уже весят достаточно много.

Я знаю, как в коде получить путь текущей временной папки (по документации *pyinstaller*):

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

В принципе, представляю, как удалять все временные папки, кроме текущей:

```
path = 'local/temp path/'
for i in os.listdir(path): # запускаем цикл в списке папок и файлов в local/temp
    if i startswith('_MEI') and not resourse_path(''): # resourse_path нужно будет просплитовать, но это не суть важно.
        os.remove(path+i)
```

Однако все упирается в то, что я без понятия, как получить путь к `appdata/Local/Temp`.
Знаю только, что `os.environ['APPDATA'`] возвращает путь до `appdata/Roaming`.

Заранее благодарю, с уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто.

1 вариант:

```
os.environ['TEMP']
```

2 вариант:

```
os.getenv('TEMP')
```